# GPS points closest to checkpoints on the road

Tags: postgis

I'm a beginner with the following situation:

There are fixed checkpoints on a road.

The GPS of a vehicle traveling on the road registers timestamped points with a certain frequency, with a low level of precision.

I need to know the timestamp of the GPS point closest to the checkpoint.The premise is that the road is unknown. I can't make the map necessary for validation. For example, to use a snap to road solution.

The premise is that the road is unknown. I can't make the map necessary for validation. For example, to use a snap to road solution.

I've made an image to illustrate.

[image]

Comment: My problem is a little different. In the question mentioned, the two points are in the same table. In my case, the points are in different tables. Can you help me with my case, please?

Comment: You can simply change the name of the table in the `cross join` (and remove the `p1.id <> id` condition)